# How do physicists use the Feynman path integral practically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, perturbation-theory

I somewhat understand how the path integral works in simple examples, I just don't get how someone can add up an infinite amount of paths. How is that even calculated?

If it's got something to do with adding wave amplitudes, I still don't get it. Isn't the whole purpose of the path integral to get away from first quantisation methods such as the wave function?

Comment: By discretizing paths.

Comment: How so?........

Comment: Have you considered consulting a textbook ok quantum mechanics?

Comment: If you are asking quantum field theory, then path integral means integration over all the possible configuration of fields in space and time. If you are asking quantum mechanics, then you integrate over all the possible quantum paths for given two points. Most of the time, classical trajectory is the stationary path, surviving after summing up all the possible paths. Yeah, by doing Feynman path integral, roughly speaking, you take weighted average over all the possible paths, weighted by wave amplitude and phase factor. Refer https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.5024926